# Simplifying hide and show div in jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I have written some jQuery code that does the job I am looking for it do but being fairly new to jQuery I was just curious to know if there was a simpler way to go about it. All its basically doing is hiding and showing divs on click events.

I have tried playing around with a few different ideas but this seems to be the only way I can get what I want to happen on the click events.

Markup below.

```js
$('#facebook-icon').click(function() {
  $('#facebook-callout, .hero-callout').fadeToggle();
  $('#twitter-icon, #linked-icon').toggleClass('z-index-neg');
});
$('#twitter-icon').click(function() {
  $('#twitter-callout, .hero-callout').fadeToggle();
  $('#facebook-icon, #linked-icon').toggleClass('z-index-neg');
});
$('#linked-icon').click(function() {
  $('#linked-callout, .hero-callout').fadeToggle();
  $('#facebook-icon, #twitter-icon').toggleClass('z-index-neg');
});

$('.close').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('div').fadeOut('slow');
  $('.hero-callout').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.social-icon').removeClass('z-index-neg');
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.hero-callout {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.close {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #151515;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.social-callout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}

.social-heading {
  color: #151515;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-transform: none;
  position: relative;
}

.z-index-neg {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.social-heading:after {
  content: "";
  background: #151515;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.social-heading:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  transition: width .5s;
}

#social-icons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-icon {
  position: relative;
  color: #151515;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.icons:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hero-wrapper">
  <div class="hero-callout">
    <h2>
      Hello World
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="social-callout" id="facebook-callout">
    <a href="#">
      <h2 class="social-heading">Facebook.</h2>
    </a>
    <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="social-callout" id="twitter-callout">
    <a href="#">
      <h2 class="social-heading">Twitter.</h2>
    </a>
    <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="social-callout" id="linked-callout">
    <a href="#">
      <h2 class="social-heading">Linked In.</h2>
    </a>
    <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
  <div id="social-icons">
    <span class="social-icon" id="facebook-icon">Facebook</span>
    <span class="social-icon" id="twitter-icon">Twitter</span>
    <span class="social-icon" id="linked-icon">Linked In</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you're looking for is called Don't Repeat Yourself, or DRY. The goal is to genericise the logic so that it can be applied to any relevant element in the DOM, so long as it follows the expected structure.

In this case you can add a `data` attribute to the `.social-icon` elements which specifies the `id` of the `.social-callout` element relates to them and should be used when clicked.

Following this pattern means you can now have an infinite number of `.social-icon` elements with associated `.social-callouts` without ever needing to amend your JS code:

```js
$('.social-icon').click(function() {
  var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
  $target.add('.hero-callout').fadeToggle();
  $('.social-icon').not(this).toggleClass('z-index-neg');
})

$('.close').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('div').fadeOut('slow');
  $('.hero-callout').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.social-icon').removeClass('z-index-neg');
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.hero-callout {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.close {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #151515;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.social-callout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}

.social-heading {
  color: #151515;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-transform: none;
  position: relative;
}

.z-index-neg {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.social-heading:after {
  content: "";
  background: #151515;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.social-heading:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  transition: width .5s;
}

#social-icons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-icon {
  position: relative;
  color: #151515;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.icons:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hero-wrapper">
  <div class="hero-callout">
    <h2>
      Hello World
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="social-callout" id="facebook-callout">
    <a href="#">
      <h2 class="social-heading">Facebook.</h2>
    </a>
    <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="social-callout" id="twitter-callout">
    <a href="#">
      <h2 class="social-heading">Twitter.</h2>
    </a>
    <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="social-callout" id="linked-callout">
    <a href="#">
      <h2 class="social-heading">Linked In.</h2>
    </a>
    <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
  <div id="social-icons">
    <span class="social-icon" id="facebook-icon" data-target="#facebook-callout">Facebook</span>
    <span class="social-icon" id="twitter-icon" data-target="#twitter-callout">Twitter</span>
    <span class="social-icon" id="linked-icon" data-target="#linked-callout">Linked In</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you very much for explaining how to go about doing this. Never really used data attributes before but will be using them more often now for similar ideas now i know how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can attach the same class to all of your elements with IDs (`'#twitter-icon', '#facebook-icon'`, etc). and then bind an event to that class. Lets say you want to put class `.icon`. Then simply do this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".icon", function(){
    $(this).fadeToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('z-index-neg');
});
```

Where `$(this)` targets the currently clicked element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for this

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the event handlers, and handle each case based on the clicked icons ID

```js
var icons = $('.social-icon').on('click', function() {
  var id = this.id.replace('icon', 'callout');
  var el = $('#' + id);
  $('.hero-callout').add(el).fadeToggle();
  icons.not(this).toggleClass('z-index-neg')
});

$('.close').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('div').fadeOut('slow');
  $('.hero-callout').fadeIn('slow');
  $('.social-icon').removeClass('z-index-neg');
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.hero-callout {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.close {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #151515;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.social-callout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}

.social-heading {
  color: #151515;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-transform: none;
  position: relative;
}

.z-index-neg {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}

.social-heading:after {
  content: "";
  background: #151515;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  transition: width .5s;
}

.social-heading:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s;
  transition: width .5s;
}

#social-icons {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-icon {
  position: relative;
  color: #151515;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.icons:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hero-wrapper">
  <div class="hero-callout">
    <h2>
      Hello World
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="social-callout" id="facebook-callout">
    <a href="#">
      <h2 class="social-heading">Facebook.</h2>
    </a>
    <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="social-callout" id="twitter-callout">
    <a href="#">
      <h2 class="social-heading">Twitter.</h2>
    </a>
    <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
  <div class="social-callout" id="linked-callout">
    <a href="#">
      <h2 class="social-heading">Linked In.</h2>
    </a>
    <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
  <div id="social-icons">
    <span class="social-icon" id="facebook-icon">Facebook</span>
    <span class="social-icon" id="twitter-icon">Twitter</span>
    <span class="social-icon" id="linked-icon">Linked In</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, not used some of the jquery code you have before so will go look up about how it works so i understand it better.